# Capturing the close of the browse for file window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filedialog

I am using infile to ask the users to browse for a file on their machine. Is there way to catch if the window is closed without file being selected?
 For example if x is clicked.

```
<input type="file" name="data" id="inFile" size="15" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this)"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean the open-file-dialog or the whole browser window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I did is:
 Start timer after the user opens the window, and in that timed function I check every 0.5 sec if the file has been selected with boolean var. I stop the timer as soon as user selects the file or HTML5 DnD occurs.  I hope this helps someone.

```
<div id="uploader"><input type="file" name="data" id="inFile" size="15" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this)"/></div>

<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="fileSelect" type="button" onmouseup="browse();">Browse</button> 

var fileselected = false;
function handleFiles(input){
    fileselected = true;
//use input
}

var interval;
function browse(){
    fileselected = false;
    var fileElem = document.getElementById("inFile");
    fileElem.click();
    interval = setInterval(setdiv, 500);

}
function setdiv(){
    if(!fileselected){  
        //do staff until user decides to Dnd or  browse for file again
        clearInterval(interval);
    }   
}
```

Comment: How does it help to catch event of closing dialog on cancelling? You timer will run forever if user clicks "Cancel" :-(

Answer (score 2):

With the solution from [HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12030686/1048572), I think you can use this:

```
<input type="file" name="data" id="inFile" />
```

```
var fileElem = document.getElementById("inFile");
var fileSelected = null;
fileElem.onclick = function(e) {
    fileSelected = this.value;
    this.value = null;
});
/* or use this in your browse() function:
    fileElem.value = null;
*/
fileElem.onchange = function(e) { // will trigger each time
    handleFileDialog(this.value === fileSelected);
};

function handleFileDialog(changed) {
    // boolean parameter if the value has changed (new select) or not (canceled)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the `blur` event will do it:

```
<input
  type="file"
  onchange="changed=true; handleFiles(this)"
  onblur="if(!changed) alert('nothing selected'); changed=false;"
/>
```

Comment: Hm, I fear this is the first event that comes when abort the selection - I see no other way.

Comment: I came here, because i just wanted highlight div under hidden fileinput when it is selected, so, use of onfocus and onblur was right solution in my case.