# getElementById returning null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm tying to read and output a text file. The Chrome console complains:

`caught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined FinanceDashBoard.html:22`"

Not sure what I am doing wrong ?

The code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Read File (via User Input selection)</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <main>
      <label>Load a text database file: <input type="file" id="txtfile" ></label>
    </main>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var dbFileElm = document.getElementById('txtfile');

  dbFileElm.onchange =  function() {
    var filePath = dbFileElm.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      output = e.target.result;
      displayContents(output);
      }
    reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
  }   

  // Ignore code below it doesn't work yet.
  function displayContents(txt) {
    var el = document.getElementById('main'); 
    el.innerHTML = txt; //display output in DOM
  }

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two mistakes.

**1) Change this line:**

```
reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
```

to this:

```
reader.readAsText(filePath);
```

*Because filePath is already: `dbFileElm.files[0];`*

**2) The `main` tag has no ID, so getting element by ID `main` will not work.**
Just edit it to:

```
<main id="main">
```

Comment: Or #2 could use `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0]`

Comment: is `main` even a valid tag in HTML5?

Comment: `main` is valid in HTML5 according to the current W3C HTML5 LC. But this is not relevant here; its being or not being valid does not affect what browsers do.

Comment: Cheers Valentin - I completely missed that.

Comment: btw, the chick in the profile pic is cruel and funny at the same time

Comment: Thanks:) Lol yap this was a test a friend suggested me to do and it works :P

Answer (score 3):

You have no elements that have `id="main"`

Try something like...

```
<main id="main"> ...
```

Or if you're trying to populate your text box...

```
var el = document.getElementById('txtfile');
```

Comment: That doesn't seem related to the error he's getting. He never tries to read property `0` of `el`.

Answer (score 0):

this post has answer to question

[HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file)

and if you set your input value to null, is working for me

```
dbFileElm.onChange =  function() {
    this.value = null;
    var filePath = dbFileElm.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      output = e.target.result;
      displayContents(output);
      }
    reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
  }
```