# Get the file path from the dialog and trigger .change() when using duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a small file upload dialog to show some images.

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#dialogImageUpload").change(function (input) {
        $(input.target.files).each(function (imageIndex, currentImage) {
            if (currentImage.type.match('image.*')){
                alert(currentImage.name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="file" id="dialogImageUpload" multiple>
    <div id="ImageListContainer"></div>
```

So you can read the name of the `currentImage`. How can I get the full path from it?

For example

```
var uploadedImage = $("<div><img src= theFilePath /></div>");
```

The second question I have is when using the file dialog, the `change` event obviously gets triggered if different files are selected as before. But what if I want to upload a file twice? The `change` event is not triggered anymore. Can I solve this somehow?

Comment: If you mean that you want to get the full client side path of the file, then you cannot. It's blocked for security reasons. You can get the file name directly from the input element, though *Edit* - in fact your code is already doing this, so I'm confused what you're asking here.

Comment: Well I got the file name but the image path is missing :/ Means I need to fill the image source with the full path

Comment: Assuming you want to preview the image that's selected you don't do it via the path, you use the binary data of the file. See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: [Filereader - upload same file again not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634616/filereader-upload-same-file-again-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You **can not** get the file path by javascript, because of the security limit by browser.
2. You can change the value to '' by JS when you click on the `file` input, so it will trigger `onchange` if you choose anything.

Comment: 1. ok 2. Do u got a little code example for me? Where do I have to put it? And what do you mean with `change the value to ''`

Comment: @peterHasemann like this: `$("#dialogImageUpload").click(function(){this.value='';})`. sorry about I can't format the code

Comment: ah yes, this works fine!