# Running code every time a file is selected via a file input, even if the selected file is the same

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I've built some component in React, that allows the user to crop a selected image file, after it is selected from a simple input type file element. I'm using the Onchange event to capture this action.

The problem is, that this event runs **only when the newly selected file is actually different than the previous one**. This is a problem, because a user might want to re-crop the same image.

The onChange event doesn't fire, if the same file is selected.

I do not have anything special in my code. This is the input element:

```
                        <input onChange={(e) => { this.onFileChange(e.target.files) }} type="file" name="file" id="exampleFile" />
```

And then the method that is run:

```
 onFileChange = (files) => {      
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload =  (e)=> {          
        this.setState(() => ({ showCropper: true, cropperSrc:reader.result }))
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);             
}
```

How can i "intercept" the file selection, even if the file is the same? Maybe some work-around?

Comment: It's because `onChange` only get's fired when the **value** changes. An easy workaround would be to clear the file inputs value in your `onFileChange` event. This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634616/filereader-upload-same-file-again-not-working

Comment: Thank you, it works. I used a ref to clear the value of the input.