# Run javascript function after file is added to upload but before submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input that accepts a file to be uploaded. The problem is that I can not figure out how to call the function after the file is added to the input.

I have tried things like onMouseMove, onClick and onChange but they do not call the function after the file is added to the input.

```
jQuery('.attachment').click(function(){
  console.log("test");
  checkFile();
});
```

Comment: doesnt `oninput` work?

Comment: Please be more specific, post the code that doesn't work. Here's a minimal demo that works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dg1hmLq3/

Comment: @pawel That solved my issue! I was using `jQuery('.attachment').click()`. I changed this to `on('change')` and it is not working. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "Add" or "Upload" button with your function in the `onclick` attribute.

`<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Upload' onclick='myUploadFunction()' />`

Answer (score 0):

[HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file)

Set the value of your  element to null on every click. Then you get a onchange event fired if a file gets selected.

```
    input.onclick = function(){
        this.value = null;
        }
    input.onchange = function(){
        alert(this.value);
    }
```