# Angular5:HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file

Tags: javascript, html, angular5

In my angular5 File upload is a trigger onchange event, but when I select the same file twice it's not selected.

My problem similar to this [HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file)

```
<input type="file" class="upload-file" onclick="this.value=null"  (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files,'doc')">
```

but its not working

Answer (score 2):

```
<input #fileInput type="file" id="fileid" (click)="fileInput.value = null" value="" (change)="handleFileInput($event)" >
```

every time you click on file input it will clear its value so even if you select the same file (change) will fire.