# Is there an event listener for on confirm files to upload?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this file input and I know I can have an onChange event on it.

```
<input type="file" name="something"  />
```

The challenge with the on change event is that If I open the file picker and choose the same file again with will not be triggered. How can I make sure I can always trigger the event?

Comment: Try the ``input`` event (``onInput``)

Comment: onInput seemed to do the same thing as change. doesn't trigger if you choose same file

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file)

Have a look at the answers - this should solve your issue

Comment: @MarioMurrent thanks for sharing that thread, and i was facing same issue too, and it will resolve it.

Comment: Yes @MarioMurrent it does. Thank you