# onclick recognized, but onchange not

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I probably stared to long at it - problem is smilar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file).I added an event listener to a button, but only the onclick method fires something. I want to display the name of the selected file from an upload:

```js
var ulButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("file-upload");
[...ulButtons].forEach(ulButton => {
  ulButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ulButton.value = null;
    console.log("this works")
  })
});


[...ulButtons].forEach(ulButton => {
  ulButton.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log("changed to:", this.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<label for="{field.id_for_label}" class="file-upload btn btn-secondary">upload file</label>
```

I fail to see why clicking on the upload button always shows in the console, but selecting a file does not trigger the `changed to: ...`.

Comment: `change` events are fired on `input` elements, not on their labels. (Or on buttons, although your "button" is in fact a label rather than a button.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work if you inlcude input field  with type `file`.

```js
var ulButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("file-upload");
[...ulButtons].forEach(ulButton => {
  ulButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ulButton.value = null;
    console.log("this works")
  })
});


[...ulButtons].forEach(ulButton => {
  ulButton.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log("changed to:", this.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<label for="{field.id_for_label}" class="file-upload btn btn-secondary">
  <input type="file">upload file</input></label>
```