# Uploading a picture in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React component has the next code:

```
              <Row>
            <Col>
                <p>Select Image</p>
                <input type="file" name="myImage" onChange={this.handle_userImage_change} />                
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <img src={this.state.userImage} />
            </Col>

          </Row>
```

and also the next callback:

```
 handle_userImage_change = (event) => {
  console.log('handle_userImage_change>event=78658');
  console.log(event)
}
```

From the event parameter I want to get the file data to convert it to base64 using readAsDataUrl so later I can assign this value to

```
this.state.userImage
```

and in this way show the respective picture at the <img ... > section.

a) What is the field from the event object I need to use?

b) Is the syntax correct for the <img ..> section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the image data from files property in event.target object like this `event.target.files[0]`. `files` is an array and the image is stored as first element.

You need to use `URL.createObjectURL()` to create an url representation of the image.
You can store this in a state variable and then use it to pass to `src` prop of the image.

```js
const [image, setImage] = useState("");

const handleFileUpload = (e) => {
  setImage(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
};

return <img src = {image} alt = "" / >
```

Note that on chrome, if you re-upload the same image again when it is already selected, `onChange` event won't trigger. Follow this to solve the issue.

[HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file).

Answer (score 3):

The above example is right but if you need to send the file/image to some backend service you might need to convert it into base64/blob.

Here is the code to convert the file to base64.

```
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

You can use base64 with img tag.

All you have to do is include  `data:image/jpg;base64,` infront of the base64 string. You can change jpg to whatever file type you want it to be

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,....."/>
```

Comment: but, in this case... will the file parameter be  e.target.files[0] ?

Comment: Ultimately getBase64 will accept a file which you can get by doing e.target.files[0].
Why it takes files as an array because you can select multiple files by passing multiple attribute in the input tag `<input type="file" multiple />` this will accept multiple files at a single time. And you can pass each file to getBase64 function to get the string.